# Make range chart zoom without filtering

Tags: dc.js

I have an ordinal bar chart that can have quite a lot of values on the x-axis. I'm trying to add a range chart to navigate the bar chart, as in this example
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/focus-ordinal-bar.html

Here is my chart with the range chart.
[image]

Here it is filtered.
[image]

When I make a selection on the range chart, the main chart filters to those values as expected. However, all the other charts update as if this was a selection.

The behaviour I'm looking for is for no filtering to happen, all that should change is the bars shown on the main chart for navigation purposes. This is the way it behaves in the Focus Ordinal Bar example.

My bar chart and range chart below. I've tried changing the group and dimension of the range chart to copies of the group and dimension, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

```
barChartTemplate
  .dimension (dimension)
  .group (group)
  .x (scaleLinear ().domain (linear_domain))
  .xUnits (dc.units.integers)
  .keyAccessor (kv => group.ord2int (kv.key))
  .elasticY (true)
  .brushOn (false)
  .dimension (dimension)
  .mouseZoomable (true)
  .zoomScale ([4, 8])
  .title (function (kv) {
    return kv.key;
  })




var rangeChart = dc.barChart ('#range');
rangeChart.filterHandler (x => {});
rangeChart
  .dimension (dimension)
  .group (group)
  .margins ({left: 40, top: 2, right: 40, bottom: 0})
  .height (20)
  .x (scaleLinear ().domain (linear_domain))
  .xUnits (dc.units.integers)
  .keyAccessor (kv => group.ord2int (kv.key))
  .valueAccessor (x => {
    return x.value.count;
  })
  .elasticY (true)
  .brushOn (true)
  .centerBar (true)
  .transitionDuration (0);

barChartTemplate.rangeChart (rangeChart);
```

Comment: Did you notice in the example that both focus and range charts had to have filtering disabled with `chart.filterHandler(function() {});` ? Indeed this example uses range/focus only for scrolling and not for filtering.

Comment: I do have the filtering disabled as in the example. It's an app with quite a bit going on elsewhere, so there are probably a few unexpected issues introduced. But it seems to be triggering a redraw based on the range currently shown on the main chart. Maybe related, it also seems to be setting the filters based on the integer values, instead of the int2ord converted values, so its as if something else is triggering filters. Appreciate hard to debug based on this limited info...

Comment: Sounds like the build-in filtering is still enabled for one chart or the other. I would put a breakpoint on `BaseMixin.filter()` and then use `this.anchorName()` (or `_chart.anchorName()` in v3) to see which chart is still filtering when you zoom. If you can't figure it out, please update your question with more complete code. Clearly this works in the dc.js focus ordinal bar example.